# Understanding top and tuning

Tags: unix, memory, top

I have allowed Postgres 30GB of RAM on our server. When running intensive tasks, I think it is swapping.

As I understand it:

- VIRT - virtual memory (ie: swapped to disk)
- RES - complete memory usage
- SHR - shared memory - I'm not clear on what this is

See attached

[image: updated top output]

I think this is saying:

- complete memory usage by Postgres ~60GB, of which 30GB is swapped
- complete memory usage by Ruby ~40GB

If this is the case, does giving Postgres another 30 or 40GB RAM seem like a good idea?

Reference

http://mugurel.sumanariu.ro/linux/the-difference-among-virt-res-and-shr-in-top-output/

Comment: And what does top say about overall memory and swap state ? I mean Total/Active/Inactive/etc ?

Comment: I've updated the screenshot. It seems to say there is a lot of free memory ... so I don't really understand the VIRT column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VIRT colums does **not** really show the total allocated memory. Rather, it only show how much memory was mapped in the process user space. In other words, its has *nothing* to do with swapping.

As a double check, give at look at the `swap` row as shown by `top`: it clearly state that used swap is at **0 KB**